# Bypass WooCommerce My-Account login for Custom login

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm creating a wholesale members only woocommerce site.  I have so far managed to lock all of woocommerce down by creating a redirect back to the my-account page for non logged in users using this bit of code I found here on stack exchange-

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || 
is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 
get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but I want to use a custom login page that I created.  www.example.com/customlogin - Where/How would I insert this into the above code? I tried but got a syntax error and spent half the day locked out of my site lol.

Next I need to tie the custom login page to the woocommerce my-account page so that I can bypass the default login that woocommerce hides in code on the same page.  So basically if a "non-logged-in user" clicks on the "my account" link they are taken to the custom login page instead.  This way I'll be able to edit the login page and my-account pages separately which I cant really do when theyre on the same page and all of my editing effect both simultaneously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the code below that will solve both of your requirements:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() ||
is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/customlogin' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> To extend condition to my account pages, I use the conditional WC tag: **`is_account_page()`** 
>   For the redirection to your custom form I use:  **`wp_redirect( home_url( '/customlogin' ) );`**

This code is tested and works